# Jest and vue test utils can`t read imports start with '~' in testing components

Tags: vue.js, testing, jestjs, vuejs3, vue-test-utils

[image: try to import store with ~]
Then i changed import from "~stores/dictionaries/address-space/administrationDistrictStore" to "stores/dictionaries/address-space/administrationDistrictStore" and it works
[image: import without ~ (error here - another ~import inside the store file)]
So jest or test-utils can`t read imports with ~ or the root folder is installed incorrectly, how i can fix that?
My solution tree:
[image: solution tree]
[image: tests and path to the stores]
[image: my test]

I tried to set modulePaths but it didn`t help
[image: jest.config.js]

I expecting that imports in components I test will work correctly

Comment: If you want that to work correctly, please adhere to the pathname resolution rules of your operating system and the systems you run on it, e.g. nodejs. As you were hit by surprise better relate to the specification of pathnames on your operating system (which you have not shared in your question). Otherwise you risk to specify pathnames that might be different than you expect. E.g. ~ at the beginning of a pathname expands on a POSIX compatible system and the result is a non-existent file or directory then as you could demonstrate in your question. Perhaps adding a slash afterwards helps.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was related with aliases for folders and skipped folders in names in the node_modules, if you have some like this:
[aliases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENU24.png)

try to set this in the jest.config.js

[config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASiVs.png)

transformIgnorePatterns for node_module aliases, moduleNameMapper for aliases in the project